# Windowing FFT: spectral leakage vs ENOB

Tags: adc, fft, cadence, spectrum

I am using Cadence to perform full speed testing of a 4-bit SAR ADC using the FFT and non-coherent sampling.

I've obtained the ENOB and the spectra of the output signal using first the rectangular window (blue,) then the Hamming window (yellow) and then the Blackman window (green).

The results are below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The spectral leakage is pretty obvious on the rectangular one hence leading to an ENOB of 0.85. On the other hand I am obtaining 3.75 with Hamming and 3.99 with Blackman, which is a pretty good result.

What I don't understand and would like to have clarification is why is the ENOB of Blackman bigger than the ENOB of Hamming, when apparently, looking at both spectra, there seems to be more lines on the Blackman one and, not only that, the energy values are bigger in that one compared to the other two.

Can someone please help me clarify what is going on here? Why is having more lines with bigger energy better in this case?

Comment: I don't think the number of lines in your FFT depends on the windowing function used.  They should only depend on the size of the FFT (DFT, actually) you're using.

Comment: @SteveSh I believe the number of lines (bins) is the same throughout, but the questioner is focusing on the number of raised bins around the fundamental.

Comment: The width of the main lobe (the fundamantal) and the sidelobe structure is a function of the weighting function chosen.  So it's not surprising that the number of "raised bins" around the fundamental is different between the 3 weighting functions chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer...

In short, you are trading better amplitude accuracy for poorer frequency accuracy (spectral linewidth) in a kind of Heisenberg uncertainty bargain.

It may help to look at these windows applied to digital lowpass filters such as FIR filters designed using the "Window method" with each of these windows. You'll see better stopband rejection with the better windows, but a wider transition band between passband and stopband.

Look at the Fourier transform of each window function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).

Hamming window  : notice the central "line" is quite narrow, but the sidebands range from -45dB to about -60dB.

Blackman window : the central line is broader (in your FFT, covers more bins) but the sidebands start about -60dB and fall rapidly off from there.

(And there are even better choices of window for amplitude accuracy if you can tolerate the frequency uncertainty from the broader central linewidth. Including the Nuttall windows, which I wish I had known about in 1982 or so)

NOTE : to compare your results with these, you would probably find a log(amplitude) plot more useful.

Comment: Good reference source you listed.  Thanks.  Then again, I have a copy of the original Harris IEEE paper "On the Use of Windows for Harmonic Analysis with the Discrete Fourier Transform", 1978.  Yeah, I'm a pack rat!